# wait for dd command to fully write to the disk

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using the dd command to create a bootable usb from iso file:

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1M
```

After pressing enter it momentarily exits and gives me:

```
915+0 records in 915+0 records out 959447040 bytes (959 MB) copied,
0.539375 s, 1.8 GB/s
```

So it's like running in background because I can see that the flash drive is working. Eventually it will stop copying and I can remove the drive successfully but the question is **why doesn't dd command wait for copying to finish. Why does it run in background. And how can I make it wait?**

Comment: Have you tried `sync`?

Comment: @choroba Does it make sense to run 'sync' if the system's already writing data to the flash drive?

Comment: I am not sure, byt `sync` might wait.

Comment: `dd` also has some sync options, for example `conv=fsync`. That said, I never had to use it with `/dev/sd*` drives myself. If you literally used `/dev/sdx` my guess would've been you had a useless 959MB file in `/dev` (ramdisk) now...

Comment: @frostschutz I used /sdc for my flash drive

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Despite popular belief, `dd` is a perfectly ordinary command, it isn't more low-level than `cat` or `cp`. Your command reads from the disk cache and writes to the disk buffers like any other command.

In order to make sure that the data is fully written to the physical media, you need to call `sync`. The command `sync` flushes all output buffers to the disk(s). When the `sync` command returns, the data has been fully written¹.

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1M; sync
```

Most of the time, you don't need to call `sync`, because unmounting a filesystem does the same job. When the `umount` command returns, or when you get a confirmation message after clicking “Eject”, the buffers have been written to the disk. Here, you're directly writing to the disk without going through a mounted filesystem, so you need to explicitly flush the buffer.

Note that instead of `dd`, you could use `tee`. This has two advantages: there's less risk of inverting the source and destination due to a typo, and it's [probably slightly faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492).

```
<~/Desktop/ubuntu.iso sudo tee /dev/sdx >/dev/null; sync
```

¹  <sub>At least on a “normal” Ubuntu system, or more generally Linux. This may not be true on other Unix-like systems or if Linux is running in a virtual environment (Cygwin, WSL, virtual machine, …). In a virtual environment, flushing writes to persistent storage may require the cooperation of the host system.</sub>

Comment: How about the "Eject" or "Safely Remove" buttons/icons. Wouldn't they also call sync before giving the "OK to remove" notification?

Comment: You likely want to use `sudo tee /dev/sdx >/dev/null`, otherwise the copying process would still be very slow due to data being written to console output.

Comment: @user68186 They don't call the `sync` command, but they do the same job under the hood.

Comment: @Gilles doesn't the kernel starts writing data to the disk once dd command puts data into memory?

Comment: @KirillIvlev It may start (depending on how much RAM is available for the disk buffers). The problem is that it isn't guaranteed to finish. `sync` tells the kernel “finish now”.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue with `dd`, only I'm writing an Arch iso. It still exits momentarily. Does this mean it puts all of the 574 MB in RAM buffer? I even tried `sync`. That exits momentarily as well. Nothing is written to the USB.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 What does “exits momentarily” mean? I think you're using the wrong English word. The data may or may not be written to the disk yet until you call `sync`. After calling `sync`, the data will be on the disk. Make sure that you've specified the right output. If you have a problem, ask a new question and explain exactly what you did and what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, sorry about "momentarily". I lazily quoted the previous guy. What I meant was calling `dd` didn't write to disk. I had tried `sync` earlier but it (kinda obviously) needs `sudo`, which I didn't use, and my ISO wasn't being written. I have about 8 GB RAM, and 6 GB remains free, so disk caching is an "issue" for me as I have the habit of pulling the drive out (no unmount). Anyways, `sudo sync` after `dd` does the job and `sync` takes about 2min, which is OK for USB 2.0. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 You don't need sudo to run `sync`, any user can run it. Pulling the drive out without unmounting makes data loss very likely. Just don't do it!

Comment: This answer is wrong. Without `conv=fdatasync`, the `dd` command does not wait to finish until the data is written to the disk, as the OP requested. Furthermore, the `sync` command schedules a sync operation, but it immediately returns; it does not wait to return until after the data are written to the disk.

Comment: @vy32 you're right `dd` won't wait for the cache to be flushed without `conv=fdatasync` etc. but on non-ancient Linux you're incorrect about `sync` not waiting. You can see [coreutils' `sync(8)` making the `sync(2)` syscall](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/86ee5548c186e82f25e1aad9bdae8edda22b7178/src/sync.c#L231). The [`sync(2)` man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html#BUGS) says "Before version 1.3.20 Linux did not wait for I/O to complete before returning." so `sync(8)` won't return until the disk acknowledges the writes (or an error is triggered).

Comment: My non-ancient version of sync (8.32) only schedules the sync, the man pages says "The writing, although scheduled, is not necessarily complete upon return from sync". Therefore I find the answer incorrect in my case.

Comment: @joaerl The `sync` program calls the `sync` system call (or library function). Under Linux, the `sync` system call does guarantee that the write returns (like on traditional Unix). GNU coreutils can run on other POSIX or Unix-like systems where the `sync` function doesn't have this guarantee, but those systems are not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdx conv=fdatasync bs=1m
```

The `conv=fdatasync` tells `dd` to use the special options to make sure that the data get written to the physical device.